# drf_yasg AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'with_ui'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Trying to documenting API using [drf_yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) according to their documentation but I got this error ***"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'with_ui'"***
here is my code in 
***urls.py***

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Blog API",
        default_version='v1',
        description="A sample API for learning DRF",
        terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="riajulkashem@gmail.com"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the library you are importing, it is `from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view`